# Dynamically construct URL for HTTP Connection Manager in SSIS Foreach Loop

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS 2012 package with a Foreach Loop Container.  For each piece of data I want to construct a URL and download the contents of that URL.  I can't seem to get the ServerUrl property of the connection to include the current piece of data from the Foreach Container.

Comment: You havent fully described your current design.  How are you attempting to set the ServerUrl property?

Comment: I added an expression to the HTTP Connection Manager that set ServerURL to "http://www.myurl.com/" + @[User::MyVar] + "/Otherstuff".  At runtime this gets evaluated to "http://www.myurl.com//Otherstuff" even though MyVar gets set by the Foreach container.  I've set DelayValidation to True for the package as I've read about this in other posts.  Still no luck.

Comment: What is the scope of the MyVar variable?

Comment: Package scope.  Originally I tried it scoped to the Foreach container but that resulted in an error.

Comment: Have you tried setting Delay Validation to False for the Data Connection object?